# How to send ERC20 token to smart contract in constructor

Tags: solidity

When deploying a smart contract to a private network, how to send ERC20 token (on the same private network) in `msg.value` to the smart contract in constructor?

Here is the contract:

```
pragma ^0.7.0;

interface ERC20 {
  //standard ERC20 functions
}
contract MyContract () {
  address erc20Contract;
  uint256 value;

  constructor (address _erc20) {
    ERC20 token = ERC20(_erc20); //_erc20 is the deployed address of ERC20 token
    erc20Contract = _erc20;
    //need to transfer msg.value token to the contract
    value = msg.value; //<<==how to transfer msg.value to the contract with ERC20 function, such as token.transfer()?
  }
}
```

Comment: "How to send ERC20 token in `msg.value`?" - That's an oxymoron, since `msg.value` denotes the amount of **ether** included in the transaction.

Comment: With `msg.value`, does it mean that `ERC20token.transfer()` has already done before submitting transaction with `msg.value`? So if it is dapp submitting a transaction, then dapp needs to do `ERC20token.transfer()` before calling contract constructor with the `msg.value`.  Isn't it?

Comment: The question may better be when submitting a transaction with `msg.value`, when the transfer of token in qty of `msg.value` needs to happen for the transaction?.

Comment: One more time - `msg.value` has nothing to do with ERC20 transfer.

Comment: hi `goodvibration`, the smart contract needs to hold token in `value`, the transfer of the token to the smart contract needs to happen. I thought calling constructor with `msg.value` and token transfer can happen at the same time in constructor. But it seems not correct.

Comment: You seem to be missing some fundamental concepts (theoretical and practical), namely the difference between Ether and Token.

Comment: I forgot to mention that all above happens on a private network instead of on Ethereum network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were already told in comments, you can't send tokens the same way you send Ethers. `msg.value` always refers to Ether value and never to tokens.

Tokens are just smart contracts which have some standard functionality. To transfer tokens the easiest way is to call the token contract's `transfer` function (if it's an ERC20 token). Yes, you can even call that in a constructor explicitly.

Comment: Hi `Lauri Peltonen`, you may help me with my understanding of `msg.value`. `msg.value` is a member of message object and assign a value to `msg.value` in transaction does not mean automatic transfer ether/token between the address of transaction sender and the address of the contract. The sender needs to explicitly transfer ether/token to the contract address if he/she really mean to send value to the contract. Is the above correct? Many thanks.

Comment: No that's not correct. The value of `msg.value` is assigned automatically by the EVM and it always means the amount of Ether sent with the transaction. And it is never related to token transfers.