# Sending ERC20 token to the constructor of a contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, constructor, erc-20-approve

I want to send an erc20 token to the constructor of a contract. I can't manually use the `approve(spender, amount)`  function before deploying the contract as the spender address needs to be the address of the contract. If I use `token.approve` or `token.transfer` methods in the contract it returns *transfer amount exceeds balance*, though I have sufficient balance in my account. I assume that it's trying to approve or transfer tokens from the contract.

Note: This question is different from [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91580/how-to-send-erc20-token-to-smart-contract-in-constructor). Using `token.approve` inside the contract approves from the contract and not from msg.sender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, you have two options:

1. Figure out the contract address in advance. Then add allowance for the contract to withdraw tokens from you, and in the constructor add `transferFrom`. Here are some details on how to figure out the address before deployment: [How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed)
2. Deploy and send tokens in a separate transaction

Comment: Hi! The first method can't be used in my application as the sender is not fixed. The sender can be any user who uses the application. I am using the second method. Thank you!